# How can i resolve this issue with Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

i'm trying to learn a little bit about Spring Boot, Rest and MVC.
So i decide to do a method that sign up the user to my database.
The method is in PostMapping and the form of my HTML is in post
I used Spring Web for the rest, JPA Repository, Thymeleaf, H2 as database, Devtools.
The problem is that my browser doesn't recognized it has a POST method and says that i am invoking a GET method.
Here is the error on console:

```
2023-03-13T16:04:50.044+01:00  WARN 38616 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported]
```

Method code:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public ModelAndView addProfile(@ModelAttribute Profilo profilo){ //ModelAndView è per il pattern MVC per restituire una pagina HTML per rappresentare il metodo.
    // @ModelAttribute viene utilizzato per mappare i dati dei parametri della richiesta HTTP all'oggetto Java corrispondente. La differenza con @RequestBody invece è nel fatto che RequestBody mappa l'intero corpo della richiesta HTTP ad un oggetto java
    //invece ModelAttribute mappa i parametri all'oggetto corrispondente

    Profilo find = repo.findByUsername(profilo.getUsername()); //variabile che istanzia il metodo di trovare il profilo per username e password
    if(!profilo.isValidPassword(profilo.getPassword())){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("profile"); // è una classe che serve per associare i dati del modello con la vista (front end) che devono essere visualizzati in risposta al client
        modelAndView.addObject("error", "La password non rispetta i requisiti, ricorda che deve contenere: " + "\n" +
                "Almeno 8 caratteri" + "\n" +
                "Un carattere grande" + "\n" +
                "Un carattere minuscolo" + "\n" +
                "Un numero da 1 a 9"); //il .addObject serve per ritornare i messaggi di errore o di successo
        return modelAndView;
    } else if (find != null) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("profile");
        modelAndView.addObject("error", "Il nome è già stato scelto, trovane un altro");
        return modelAndView;
    }
    repo.save(profilo);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("profile");
    modelAndView.addObject("success", "Il profilo è stato aggiunto con successo");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Front-end code inserted into the folder "templates":

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>User Registration Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>User Registration Form</h1>
<form method="POST" action="/add">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required><br>

  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have `@PostMapping` on the controller method?

Comment: If you are using Tomcat server for your application, POST is not supported by Tomcat by default.

Comment: Typing the url into the address bar of your browser will be treated as a GET. use curl or postman or a browser extension to make POST calls